# Where to download Web Farm Framework and External Cache for IIS 8?

Tags: iis, iis-8, url-rewrite-module, web-farm-framework

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard (x64-based processor), and it has IIS 8. I need to configure reverse proxy on it, and it is missing the URL Rewrite module. From what I have read, URL Rewrite requires the Application Request Routing (ARR) module, which itself also requires the Web Farm Framework module and External Cache module.

For URL Rewrite, I can download from https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

For ARR, I can download from https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing

Where can I download Web Farm Framework and External Cache modules for IIS 8? I have searched and what I have found so far are only for up to IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to download what I needed and got the reverse proxy to work. In case anyone is interested, here are the steps to install all the necessary modules.

1. Stop IIS 8 first by entering "`net stop was /y`" in a command window.
2. Download URL Rewrite from this link and install it:
   https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

   To use the reverse proxy function in URL Rewrite module, the Application Request Routing module is required, which itself requires the Web Farm Framework module and External Cache module.
3. Download Web Farm Framework module from this link and install it:
   http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/7/0/57065640-4665-4980-a2f1-4d5940b577b0/webfarm_v1.1_amd64_en_us.msi
4. Download External Cache module from this link and install it:
   https://web.archive.org/web/20161025003123/http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/4/1/3415F3F9-5698-44FE-A072-D4AF09728390/ExternalDiskCache_amd64_en-US.msi

   <s>http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/4/1/3415F3F9-5698-44FE-A072-D4AF09728390/ExternalDiskCache_amd64_en-US.msi</s>
5. Download Application Request Routing module from this link and install it:
   https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing
6. Go to Windows services and start "World Wide Web Publishing Service", which is IIS.

Comment: Thanks for that web farm link Microsoft is fubar and their links all 404 off iis.net site.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here trying to install External Cache 1.1 to use AAR 2.5 / 3.0 on IIS 8.5 + Windows 2012, the web archive link is https://web.archive.org/web/20200802223752/https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/A/5/CA5FAD87-1E93-454A-BB74-98310A9C523C/ExternalDiskCache_amd64.msi

Comment: Better [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41713348/edit) the answer directly rather than using an answer as comment